# How to clear values after AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a problem of getting old values after an AJAX call. 
I have a button to save the values in the `TextArea and DropDownBox`.When button is click, it takes `TextArea and DropDownBox` values to the `controller` and save in the `Database`.
Now the problem is when I entered values in those input fields for the second time I am getting an old values.

Here is my ajax code:-

```
var pickupIssueTypeId = $("#PickupId").val(); // Here I am getting an old values 
var pickupIssueNote = $("#Note").val();       // old values


$.ajax({
    url: '/Orders/AddPickup',
    data: postData,
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    //cache:'false',            // <---- couldn't help me
    success: function (result)
    {
        $("#divOrderItemsContainer").html(result);
    },

 <table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        List of Items
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Items:
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id ="issuedItems">
            </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Pickup Issue:
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PickupId, new SelectList(Model.OrderPickupIssueTypeSelectListItems, "Value", "Text",""), new { style = "width:306px", @class = "watermark" }) %>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Note:
    </td>
    <td>
         <%= Html.TextAreaFor("Note", new { style = "width:350px;height:100px;", @class = "fieldRequired watermark" }) %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I also tried by adding `ModelState.Clear()` didn't help me.

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by enter the fields for a second time?  Can you show that code?

Comment: Are you getting the old values in jquery or in controller?

Comment: @Jatin I am getting old values in jquery

Comment: Have you debugged your jquery code to find out what is data in `postData` while submitting it throug ajax?

Comment: FYI, I have posted my view code as well. Thank you for trying to help me. I checked in debug. After putint new values in those fields and click the button I am getting old values.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a form to take the inputs. Right?
If your formid is 'FormId' you can try the following after success of the ajax call.

```
$('#FormId')[0].reset();
```

Comment: Actually I am using `dialogbox`.